# DocuSign Post Template REST API call error "UNABLE_TO_LOAD_DOCUMENT"

Tags: rest, docusignapi

When I perform a simple call to the DocuSign REST API ([Post Template](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Post%20Template.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____116)), I get the following error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "UNABLE_TO_LOAD_DOCUMENT",
    "message": "Unable to load the document. Unable to load Document(1: document.pdf). Document is password protected, please remove password protection before using the document."
}
```

But document isn't password protected. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you read the DocuSign API docs and help pages?

Comment: Yes, I have. But I haven't found any additional information. Here is the [Error Codes List](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#Error%20Code/Error%20Codes%20and%20Associated%20Messages.htm%3FTocPath%3DError%2520Code%2520Information|_____1).

Comment: Are you able to share your PDF Bytes?

Comment: No, I can't. Maybe somebody can share the working example of the raw HTTP request?

Comment: I've sometimes seen this error returned when the format isn't recognized.  For instance, if you are uploading a Word doc but the "extension" value is set to PDF.  Some other things to consider:  Are you encoding in Base64?  Is your request body matching up with the document id?  If you can't share the doc, can you share the request body?

Comment: Have you tested with other PDFs?  If other PDFS yield the same result then it's a problem with your code.  If they work then it's a problem with that specific doc.

Comment: Thanks for good questions. Finally I have uploaded the template, but I have got another error message on the DocuSign dashboard (when I trying to view uploaded template document): "Document not available".

Comment: @tooleks Did you ever figure out root cause of all of this?

Comment: In the error message: Document is password protected, please remove password protection before using the document. Have you tried a non-password protected PDF?

Comment: @timlah79, it's been a long time ago, but if I remember correctly, I resolved the issue by using [DocuSign SOAP API](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm) for this call. Maybe it will be helpful to somebody.

Comment: @PaulMobilio, yes I've tried non-password protected PDF, as I mentioned in my question above, but no results.

Comment: @tooleks : When you view the PDF document properties and go to the Security tab, can you list the different restrictions you have in place ?